# celery with flask: application not registered on db instance and no application bound to current context

Tags: flask, celery

I'm trying to add some background tasks to my flask app using celery. I'm using blueprint with my flask app like this:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object('config')
    db.init_app(app)

    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)
    from .api_1_0 import api as api_1_0_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(api_1_0_blueprint, url_prefix='/api/v1.0')

    return app
```

And I have `run.py` like this:

```
app = create_app()
app.run(port=7000, debug=True, threaded=True)
```

Then I have a separate file with some tasks:

```
celery = Celery(__name__, broker=CELERY_BROKER_URL)


@celery.task
def send_async_sms(to, msg):
    app = current_app._get_current_object()
    with app.app_context():
        time.sleep(12)
        print "Sending to {0}: {1}".format(to, msg)
```

Without the two lines with app context, things work fine. But adding them cause the following problem:

```
 ERROR/MainProcess] Task app.notify.send_async_sms[0d535fc4-7465-470e-9204-548ecca2c6e0] raised unexpected: RuntimeError('working outside of application context',)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `current_app` depends on an app context existing. replace that with `create_app`, and you should be able to create and work in a new context without issue.